# REST API set a nonexistent parameter

Tags: rest, quire-api

Why can I send some parameters in the request that are not described in the documentation. 
For example, "iconColor" when creating the [board](https://quire.io/api/board/), I pass

```js
{
    "name": "Test Board",
    "iconColor": "45"
}
```

and returns

```js
{
    "oid": "VfTDY8NtENjg5KDMObdFJCWx",
    "project": "zxoyOUci8yDC.eK.wwsocWbY",
    "id": "Test_Board",
    "name": "Test Board",
    "description": "",
    "iconColor": "45", 
    ...
}
```

Why i can set "iconColor", in the [documentation](https://quire.io/dev/api/#tag-board) there is no such parameter!

Comment: What's the exact problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like inconsistent documentation, most likely a new field that was added without updating the API docs.

As I am writing this it just got updated, and the new fields were added to the API docs.

https://quire.io/dev/api/#tag-board